# The code pauses its work and doesn't reach the output. C language

Tags: c

I wrote a code that has to determinate the largest negative element of the array in range [X, Y] and delete it. After that the "updated" version of the array without that one element shows up on the screen. The number of array elements, the values of array elements, X and Y values are typed in by a user.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int n, i, X, Y;
    printf("Type in the number of array elements: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    if (n <= 0) {
        printf("The number of array elements must be a positive value. \n");
        return 1;
    } 

    /* Dynamic memory allocation */
    int* arr = (int*)malloc(n * sizeof(int));
    
    /* Checking in if the dynamic memory allocation went successfully */
    if (arr == NULL) {
        printf("A dynamic memory allocation went unsuccessfully. \n");
        return 1;
    } 

    printf("Type in the array elements' values. \n");

    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        printf("%d element: ", i + 1);
        scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
    } 

    do {
        printf("Type in space-separated X and Y values (x < 0): ");
        scanf("%d %d", &X, &Y);

        if (X >= 0) {
            printf("X must be a negative value. \n");
        }   
    } while (X >= 0);

    int last_negative = 1;
    int maxx = arr[0];
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        if (arr[i] >= X && arr[i] <= Y && arr[i] < 0) {
            last_negative = 0;
            if (arr[i] > maxx) {
                maxx = arr[i];
            }
        } 
    } 

    if (last_negative == 1) {
        printf("There are no array elements in range [%d, %d].\n", X, Y);
        free(arr); /* Freeing the allocated memory */
        return 1;
    } 

    /* Deleting the largest negative element that we founded */
    for (i = maxx; i < n - 1; ++i) {
        arr[i] = arr[i + 1];
    } 

    /* Reducing the array length by one */
    arr = (int*)realloc(arr, (n - 1) * sizeof(int));

    printf("The largest negative element in range [%d, %d] was deleted.\n The final outcome: \n", X, Y);
    for (i = 0; i < n - 1; ++i) {
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    } 

    /* Freeing the allocated memory */
    free(arr);
    return 0;
}
```

I'm new in C programming so I might not understand some things well. I know something is wrong with my code but I really can't say what exactly is wrong. Hope to recieve some help :(

Comment: How do you know something is wrong?  Can you simplify it (e.g. by removing all user input) and post an [mcve]?  What is the difference between its expected behavior and actual behavior?

Comment: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: @DavidGrayson The outcome must contain all the elements of the array (separated by a space) without the largest negative element that was found. The actual behavior is different. After I run my code it pauses on the stage of finding that one element and just goes like this... I'm not getting the outcome even with 5 more minutes of waiting or more.

Comment: Not a single `scanf` return value is checked.

Comment: As @JonathonReinhart indicates, you cannot use `scanf()` correctly unless you ***check the return***. Also in C, there is no need to cast the return of `malloc`, it is unnecessary. See: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714) And see [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) Debugging is a skill that is just as important as coding itself. In fact, it is a necessary part of the process. You can't do one without the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like there are a few issues in your code. I've made some modifications to address those issues:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int n, i, X, Y;
    printf("Type in the number of array elements: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    if (n <= 0) {
        printf("The number of array elements must be a positive value. \n");
        return 1;
    } 

    /* Dynamic memory allocation */
    int* arr = (int*)malloc(n * sizeof(int));
    
    /* Checking if dynamic memory allocation was successful */
    if (arr == NULL) {
        printf("Dynamic memory allocation was unsuccessful. \n");
        return 1;
    } 

    printf("Type in the array elements' values. \n");

    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        printf("%d element: ", i + 1);
        scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
    } 

    do {
        printf("Type in space-separated X and Y values (X < 0): ");
        scanf("%d %d", &X, &Y);

        if (X >= 0) {
            printf("X must be a negative value. \n");
        }   
    } while (X >= 0);

    int last_negative = 1;
    int maxx = arr[0];
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        if (arr[i] >= X && arr[i] <= Y && arr[i] < 0) {
            last_negative = 0;
            if (arr[i] > maxx) {
                maxx = arr[i];
            }
        } 
    } 

    if (last_negative == 1) {
        printf("There are no array elements in the range [%d, %d].\n", X, Y);
        free(arr); /* Freeing the allocated memory */
        return 1;
    } 

    /* Deleting the largest negative element that we found */
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        if (arr[i] == maxx) {
            for (int j = i; j < n - 1; ++j) {
                arr[j] = arr[j + 1];
            }
            break;  // Exit the loop once the element is found and deleted
        }
    } 

    /* Reducing the array length by one */
    arr = (int*)realloc(arr, (n - 1) * sizeof(int));

    printf("The largest negative element in the range [%d, %d] was deleted.\n The final outcome: \n", X, Y);
    for (i = 0; i < n - 1; ++i) {
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    } 

    /* Freeing the allocated memory */
    free(arr);
    return 0;
}
```

1. **Dynamic Memory Allocation:**

   - The code uses dynamic memory allocation with `malloc` to create an array of integers. However, it doesn't free this memory if an error occurs or when the program exits normally. This could lead to memory leaks.
2. **Loop Condition for Deleting Largest Negative Element:**

   - The loop condition for deleting the largest negative element is incorrect. It uses `for (i = maxx; i < n - 1; ++i)`, but it should be `for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)` because you want to iterate through the entire array to find and delete the largest negative element.
3. **Reallocating Memory:**

   - After deleting the largest negative element, the code reallocates memory using `realloc`. However, this is done without checking whether the `realloc` operation is successful or not. If the reallocation fails, the program may encounter issues.
4. **Loop Condition for Finding Largest Negative Element:**

   - The loop condition for finding the largest negative element is not robust. It initializes `maxx` with `arr[0]` and then iterates from the beginning to find the largest negative element. It's okay, but the code could be clearer by starting the loop from index 1 since `maxx` is already initialized with `arr[0]`.
5. **Deleting the Largest Negative Element:**

   - The code uses `arr[i] = arr[i + 1];` to delete the largest negative element. However, it does not handle the last element properly. It should reduce the array length by one after deleting the element and not attempt to access the now out-of-bounds element.
6. **Loop Condition for Printing Final Outcome:**

   - The loop condition for printing the final outcome uses `for (i = 0; i < n - 1; ++i)`. However, since the array length has been reduced by one after deleting the largest negative element, it should be `for (i = 0; i < n - 1; ++i)`.
7. **Minor Message Improvements:**

   - Minor improvements in the wording of messages for better clarity.

The modified code in my response addresses these issues. It frees the dynamically allocated memory, corrects the loop conditions, and adds checks for the success of memory operations.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831/10871073

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely experiencing an infinite loop or a very slow loop.

`i = maxx` is wrong, because `i` is an array index, and `maxx`  is a value. To fix it, you may want to add a new array index variable `maxi`, and do `maxi = i;`, and later `i = maxi;`.

To debug this further, add lots of `printf`s (between each code line), and see how many times each gets printed.